# How can we do a Group By on Multiple fields and Select First or Max?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I just concatenated two data frame together. That step is fine. Now I am trying to figure out how to do some kind of sort, group by, and select the first item.  I think the code should be something like this (but this doesn't work).

First attempt:

```
df_final = df_final.sort_values('location','project_type','data_date', ascending=True).drop_duplicates('location','project_type','data_date', keep='first')
```

Second attempt:

```
df_final = df_final.groupby(['location','project_type'], sort=True)['data_date','ltd_spending'].max()
```

I want to group by location, project_type, and data_date, and keep the row with the maximum date.  Here is a small sample of my data.

[image]

So, it would be max date and max spending, per location and project.  I think I have to fill down to impute the blanks as well.  Maybe there's some way to automatically do that in Pandas...not sure.

I want to end up with this.

[image]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing square brackets [ and ] in

```py
df_final = df_final.sort_values('location','project_type','data_date', ascending=True).drop_duplicates('location','project_type','data_date', keep='first')
```

It should be

```py
df_final = df_final.sort_values(['location','project_type','data_date'], ascending=True).drop_duplicates(['location','project_type','data_date'], keep='first')
```

Use keep='first' for min value, 'last' for max since you've sorted the dataset.

It is equivalent of doing a `groupby(...).min()` or a `groupby(...).max()`

Comment: I guess it's hard to see these things after working all day long, with no break at all. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This should sort you out now that you want to keep latest date and  max spending.

```
 df.groupby(['location', 'project_type']).max()
```